# On Mikrotik RouterOS, is it possible to get Netflow information from a bridged connection?

Tags: bridge, mikrotik, netflow, routeros

I have a RouterOS box set up to bridge two ethernet connections. I have `use-ip-firewall=yes` in the bridge configuration, so that the ports go through the firewall.

I've enabled netflow reporting via `ip/traffic-flow`, but the only packets I see reported are broadcast and multicast packets, not the packets that are flowing through the bridge. The documentation indicates that traffic flow logging happens after firewall processing and that it won't work with bridged connections by default, but I would have thought that `use-ip-firewall=yes` ought to address this.

Is it possible to make this work somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I think the basis for their NetFlow support is centered on open source technologies. We tried to [configure Mikrotik NetFlow](http://www.plixer.com/products/netflow-sflow/configure-netflow-sflow.php) with Scrutinizer NetFlow & sFlow Analyzer and it wasn't possible at that time, which was about a year ago. If things have changed with their NetFlow support since then, we would certainly be willing to run more tests. Please send us a packet capture, if we can be of any help.

Comment: I've got it set up to pipe into flowd, but AFAICT it's nothing to do with the collector. I believe the data just isn't being sent out from the router -- I get the multicast and broadcast packets OK, which makes me think that flowd is set up perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

IP firewalled bridges will only monitor flows for packets crossing your bridge, meaning that any connection between machines located in the same side of your bridge won't be shown in NetFlow as packets never reach your router.

If you ping a node located in the remote side of the bridge, you should be able to monitor in "/ip firewall connections" both broadcast ARP packets requesting the remote node IP, and then the established ICMP connections, this time crossing your router.